# Is styling also defined in vector data or all in style.json

Tags: style, vector-layer, maptiler, openmaptiles, maplibre-gl

I'm using the style editor in maptiler cloud with an openmaptiles base map. It uses opacity and zoom stops to transition between different layers as you zoom in. For example, landcover_wood shows from zoom 24 to 7, then landcover_forestland fades in around zoom 10 to 0. However, I deleted all of the stops (no min zoom, 24 max zoom), and the layers still disappear at those zoom levels.

```
{
  "id": "landcover_wood",
  "type": "fill",
  "source": "openmaptiles",
  "source-layer": "landcover",
  "maxzoom": 24,
  "layout": {"visibility": "none"},
  "paint": {
    "fill-color": "rgba(59, 126, 7, .4)",
    "fill-opacity": 1,
    "fill-antialias": false
  },
  "metadata": {},
  "filter": [
    "all",
    ["==", "class", "wood"]
  ]
}
```

I'm wondering if there is something defined in the source vector data that says landcover_wood doesn't exist after zoom of 7. Or is this a bug, or something else I'm not taking into account? I've turned off every other layer so something else isn't covering it at those zooms.

Also, in QGIS I am able to edit the style (placement, font, etc) of labels. If I export this as vector data/shape file, and upload it to maptiler or use it with maplibre, will that styling be lost completely? Or is it only overridden by the render library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers in different map styles are displayed relative to conditions
such as map purpose, usage, number of features, etc.

The process is called generalization and it includes any changes in a map that are made
when deriving a smaller-scale map from a larger-scale map or map data.

Because of generalization, some of the map-producing companies upload only
a limited amount of tiles into the map repository which also applies to MapTiler.

The layer "landcover_wood" does not contain map tiles outside the range that is specified in the map style by MapTiler.
In other words, only adjusting the sliders in the style editor will not make this layer appear, because the tiles for those other layers do not exist in the MapTiler Cloud.

That is to avoid situations when e.g. a low-level road network would suddenly appear in higher zoom levels and would cover most of the map's surface, making the map hard to read.